# the figure is flashing too bad after adding annotation to matlab figure

Tags: matlab, animation, annotations, plot

I am trying to plot animation with matlab by the following code

```
height = 0.5;
for temp=1:1000
  clf('reset');
  height = 0.5-temp/1000;
   annotation(gcf,'rectangle',[0.957845238095236-0.1 0.1595238095238094 0.00941666666666667 height],'FaceColor',[1 0 0]);
   x = rand(1, 20);
   y = rand(1, 20);
   plot(x, y, '.', 'markersize', 5);
   axis([0 1 0 1]);
   drawnow;
end
```

If I hide the annotation code, it runs pretty good, but if the annotation was there, it flashes pretty bad and slow down the simulation pretty bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can comment out the `clf('reset');` line to solve this issue...

Comment: but I need to clean the figure before plotting the next frame, any replacement to clean that instead?

Comment: Have you even _tried_ ? if you don't use `hold on` or similar you don't need to clear the figure. Every time you `plot` the figure data is cleared. As for the annotation, you overwrite it, so what's the problem here?

Comment: Yes. For this one, I didn't need to clear that. What just like what you said, if I extend it to something need hold on and without clf('reset'), how to clean the figure Thanks

Comment: oh, I just figure that I could use hold off to clean the figure also, sorry for that :)